# Keras custom layer: change values of tensor based on conditions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to write a custom keras layer, which changes the values of a tensor. However, numpy syntax doesn't work. I think the code is self-explaining:

```
class myLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shapes):
        super(myLayer, self).build(input_shapes)

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        inputs[(inputs>0) & (inputs<1)] = 1
        inputs[inputs<=0] = K.exp(inputs)
        inputs[inputs>1] = K.exp(1-inputs)
        return inputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shapes):
        return input_shapes
```

How to write the assignments with tensorflow and still allow backprop?

Comment: For more background, i try to implement the REG-GAN explained in  https://openreview.net/pdf/90f0e675457dac151517a5ed5c0f15d856366494.pdf where the Kernel-Function is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function does not have trainable parameters, thus, you should use a `Lambda` layer, that will spare you the trouble of writing so much (but what you did is not a problem either).

```
def customCall(inputs):

    ones = K.ones_like(inputs)
    lower = K.exp(inputs)
    higher = K.exp(1-inputs)

    outputs = K.switch(K.greater(inputs,1), higher, ones)
    outputs = K.switch(K.less_equal(inputs,0), lower, outputs)

    return outputs
```

The layer:

```
Lambda(customCall)
```

**Warning:**

The section with outputs equal to one has gradients equal to zero. This region might get stuck in training.

Comment: +1, I was not aware of `K.switch`. I was writing a solution based on creating masks (greater than 1, less than 1, etc.) and multiplying them, then I saw your answer.